# One model for viewing(viewmodel) and one model for forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, viewmodel

While doing some changes in my application to use viewmodels instead of domain models. I came up with this problem. There are some fields that are not used when create new item ex:CreatedDate... but I need them when viewing list of items or item details.

I have seen tutorials where they use viewmodels for everything on front-end.

So is it a good practice to have one more model for forms where I expose only fields that are needed for creating items while there are models for viewing and domain models for back-end operations? Or is there a better approach for this problem?

Comment: A ViewModel is there to support _a_ (1) View. Reuse for different Views is a bonus but not a goal. You could use inheritance here to create a family of related VMs. Or use composition, forward a Model property.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose only domain model to transfer data from logical abstraction to your view abstraction  without using  models for view